python2.7 - How to decode JSON without decoding the UTF-8 inside of it?
I need a function to decode UTF-8 encoded JSON. This function should take a UTF-8 encoded JSON string and convert it to UTF-8 encoded objects. The following code works:
# helper function
def Obj_To_UTF8(o):
    res = {}
    for k, v in o.items():
        k = k.encode('utf-8')
        v = v.encode('utf-8') if isinstance(v, unicode) else v
        res[k] = v
    return res

# Load UTF-8 encoded JSON to UTF-8 encoded objects
def Load_JSON(s):
    return json.loads(s, object_hook = Obj_To_UTF8)

but is rather ridiculous, as json.loads is decoding the UTF-8 just so we can encode it again. How can I decode JSON without decoding the UTF-8 inside of it?
Background
I emphasize that the JSON is already UTF-8 encoded. This is important because I want to process the decoded JSON in exactly the same character encoding as the encoded JSON, using the same byte-based functions I use to process files, sockets, etc. Therefore, for best modularity, we should not bring unicodes into the program. (If we were changing the encoding or writing a text editor or font renderer, that would be the place to bring in unicodes. If we're not doing those things, then unicodes and the associated encoding/decoding are just a headache. Hopefully the example above illustrates this pretty well.)
For those unfamiliar with UTF-8, it is designed to support matching and tokenization directly on the bytes, specifically so that it is compatible with encoding-agnostic software (some of which is over 50 years old and still kicking). Languages like C and Python2 make it easy to process strings directly in bytes, and therefore avoid constantly encoding and decoding strings.
Unfortunately, json.loads seems to stray from these principles, for no obvious good reason. I can think of only two reasons why a JSON implementation would even care about character encoding:

The \u feature, which is optional (and turned off by default in web browsers, so that they tend to emit UTF-8 sequences for non-ASCII characters).
Validating that the received string is proper UTF-8. Hopefully this pedantry would also be optional. (Apart from the UTF-8 fiat, JSON's actual delimiting scheme works perfectly well with binary data.)

So maybe the JSON implementation cares about the character encoding, but forcing all JSON applications to deal with character encoding is poor modularity: rather than separating concerns, it unnecessarily ties JSON decoding to UTF-8 decoding. So a decent JSON implementation would at least provide a way to disable the UTF-8 decoding.

is it possible to use Python 3? otherwise you might be able to run your program as utf-8 by setting this in in the file header # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

@ti7 I added # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- to the top of the file, but json.loads('"hello"') still returns a doggone unicode. I am using some Python 2 libraries, so Python 3 is not an option. Also in my limited experience with Python 3, it is far worse when it comes to superfluous UTF-8 decoding. Having said that, if Python 3 provides a solution, this could be informative.

JSON is UTF-8 by default, no need to mention that. Also, every JSON string is Unicode, even if it only uses the ASCII subset thereof, so the type  in Python will be unicode, which absolutely makes sense. Why do you want raw bytes instead? I believe challenging that approach could lead to better results.

@Ulrich I've added a few paragraphs which hopefully answer your questions.

While I can't possibly recommend this "solution", you're already using an unsupported language
If you are developing new code, stop and consider if you have an XY Problem and if you could at minimum wrap whatever you're doing in Python 3's subproces to begin to move away from it
That said, you might be able to leverage my wildly evil solution to another Question and directly interpret the JSON as a Python dict/collection
Serious Cautions About Untrusted Inputs

this can and will execute whatever is in the passed file path, which may do anything the Python interpreter running under your user can do (which is probably anything a computer can do) and that input need not even be JSON-like to be exec()'d!
do not provide a route for this to access untrusted input of any kind (for example from a web client), a malicious input can trivially take over your system - only consider as a last option and for local files with a known and fixed content!

test.json
{
  "1": "➀"
}

test.py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
def thisisterribledonotdothis(path):
    with open(path) as fh:
        exec("null=None;true=True;false=False;d={}".format(fh.read()))
    return locals()["d"]

import sys
d = thisisterribledonotdothis(sys.argv[1])
print(d)

% docker run --rm -it -v .:/root/mount python:2.7 python2 /root/mount/test.py /root/mount/test.json
{'1': '\xe2\x9e\x80'}

Further notes and cautions

seems to work with and without explicit coding line, but ymmv
the "official" python:2.7 container above, while just to show how this could work, is positively ancient and has literally hundreds of known vulnerabilities, to work inside one, consider crafting your own container from something at least remotely supported like Ubuntu 16.04 instead
a major reason to move to Python 3 is hugely better strings-vs-bytes and overall unicode handling


These are great observations: that Python 2 code itself keeps its own character encoding when it runs. Also that JSON is a subset of Python 2, along with the security concerns around exec. (I would disagree that Python 3 is an upgrade when it comes to string handling. Python 3 restricts byte-string literals to ASCII, and generally makes it harder to write encoding-agnostic byte-string code, by burying the byte-string functions deeper into the standard library objects. Writing file and socket code in Python 3 is a constant struggle against the language.)
